# Parallel for nested loops in openmp

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have problem to parallel for-loop code in OpenMP, result of parallel for-loop is different with a sequential for-loop. How to make this code parallel with same result as sequential code.

```
const long nx = 20;
const long ny = 20;
const long nz = 20;
int i, j, k, a, v;

#pragma omp parallel private(tid_2, i,j,k,a,v) shared(numt_2,nx,ny,nz)
{
    numt_2 = omp_get_num_threads();
    tid_2 = omp_get_thread_num();
    printf("Thread %d Total thread%d\n", tid_2, numt_2);

#pragma omp parallel for collapse(4) //num_threads(3)
for (i = 0; i <= nx; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j <= ny; j++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k <= nz; k++)
        {
            for (a = 0; a < 19; a++)
            {
                ff[fineindex(i, j, k, a)] = 0.0;

                //#pragma omp barrier

                for (v = 0; v < 19; v++)
                {          
                    ff[fineindex(i, j, k, a)] += Minv2[a][v] * rf[v];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: use `#pragma omp for` without `parallel`.

Comment: You cannot divide 21 calculations across 4 threads. Consider using non-obscure control expressions of your for loops instead: `i <= nx` change to `i < nx`. Also why do you iterate over 21 items in one case and 19 in another? Shouldn't you rather always iterate over 20 items?

Comment: I would also consider changing the order of those nested loops in ``` a -> v -> k -> i -> j``` and, if ```fineindex(i, j, k, a)``` is a biunivocal function you can initialise the array to 0 only once (taking advance of vectorisation, if possible).

Comment: How different? Round off or really diffrent?

Comment: Declare all of your variables in their minimum scope. (We're not in the 1970s now). (And, think about the sharing of `v`,  which is not included in your collapsed OpenMP loops...). It's also not clear from this code whether `fineindex` (which is maybe intended to be `findindex`?)  can generate the same output value for multiple different input values. If so there's a race there too.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer `parallel` region will execute the inner `parallel for` region multiple times. Assume there are 8 cores on your machine, the loops will be calculated 8 times, compared to the sequential version only running loops once.

`ff` is implicitly shared between threads in the parallel region. Therefore, during the computation, data race may exist for `ff[fineindex(i, j, k, a)]`. Since 8 threads are working on `ff` at the same time, when two threads try to write to the same index of `ff`, it may lead to an unpredicted result.

To resolve this issue, you may use `omp for` instead of `omp parallel for` for the loops. `omp for` is just used for worksharing, which distributes your loop iterations to the threads in the outer parallel region. It will not start another parallel region. In this way, each thread in the outer parallel will handle different loop iterations.